# Makefile mirror build directory

Tags: makefile, mirror

I need to create Makefile that compiles .c files with a lot of subdirs (sources directory goes in around 5 level depth) and I need to place the object files in the mirrored build directory. So far, I have created this Makefile:

```
CC := gcc.exe
AS := as.exe

CFLAGS = -DCORE_SW_VERSION='"$(CORE_SW_VERSION)"' -Wall -mA6 -c -fmessage-length=0 -Hsdata0
CFLAGS += -fgnu89-inline -mno-volatile-cache $(INCLUDE)  -Hon=each_function_in_own_section -Xcrc -std=c99 -O1

CORE_SW_VERSION:=CORE.07.01.04.01.03.01.R
HAL_SW_VERSION:=16.01.06.01.06.00

MODE_CORE := dev
MODE_HAL := dev


OBJDIR := $(shell pwd)/$(TARGET12)  #TARGET12 is a make parameter
INCLUDE := $(shell cat ./$(TARGET12)_include.txt)
SOURCEDIR := ../sources

CSRC := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.c')
EXCLUDES := $(shell cat ./$(TARGET12)_exclude.txt)

OBJ := $(CSRC:.c=.o)
OBJS := $(patsubst ../%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(CSRC)) 


.PHONY: $(TARGET12)
$(TARGET12): $(OBJS)
    $(AR) -r $(CORE_SW_VERSION).a $(OBJS)   


$(OBJS): $(CSRC)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(patsubst ../%,$(OBJDIR)/%,$@)
```

If I define rule for `$(OBJS)` this way, `$<` is always the first .c file in `$(CSRC)`.

If I define `$(OBJS)` this way:

```
$(OBJS): %.o: %.c
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CP) $< $@
```

I get error that there is no rule to make target for .c file. But I see that make is looking for .c file in build mirrored directory, and it should look at the source dir. Do you maybe know how this could be arranged?

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule `$(OBJS): %.o: %.c` means something like this: when trying to create a `.o` file, use this rule if the corresponding `.c` file exists. For example: when make is looking for a way to create `$(OBJDIR)/foo.o`, it will look for `$(OBJDIR)/foo.c`.

In your case this file does not exists, so the rule is ignored.

What you want is rather something like this:

```
$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CP) $< $@
```

Comment: lesmana, thank you for your reply! Actually, it was

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : ../%.c
 @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

that finished the job! Thanks a lot! You helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The first rule for `$(OBJS)` you tried, states that every object file individually depends on all source files. Surely that's not correct.
Your second attempt is better, although the recipe is weird. Fix that and use `VPATH` to make `make` find the sources.